# How to broadcast a pandas dataframe with a single row dataframe?

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe(dall), and I have a single row dataframe that has the same columns (row). 
How to get d_result without writing a loop? I understand I can convert dataframe to numpy array and broadcast, but I would imagine Pandas has a way to do it directly. I have tried pd.mul, give me nan results.

```
dall = pd.DataFrame([[5,4,3], [3,5,5], [6,6,6]], columns=['a','b','c'])
row = pd.DataFrame([[-1, 100, 0]], columns=['a','b','c'])
d_result = pd.DataFrame([[-5,400,0], [-3,500,0], [-6,600,0]], columns=['a','b','c'])
```

dall

```
    a   b   c
0   5   4   3
1   3   5   5
2   6   6   6
```

row

```
    a   b   c
0   -1  100 0
```

d_result

```
     a  b   c
0   -5  400 0
1   -3  500 0
2   -6  600 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `mul`

```
dall=dall.mul(row.loc[0],axis=1)
dall
Out[5]: 
   a    b  c
0 -5  400  0
1 -3  500  0
2 -6  600  0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by multiplying DataFrame obj to Series obj. Something like this:

```
dall * row.iloc[0]
```

I think this is essentially same as @WeNYoBen answer.

You can also multiply DataFrame obj to DataFrame obj like below. But be careful that NaN value will not propagate, because NaN value will be replaced to 1.0 before multiplication.

```
dall.mul(row, axis='columns', fill_value=1.0)
```